# URL Rewrite if GET parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect/RewriteRule a Url when there is a special parameter in it
for example
/post/path/?code=1
redirect to
/post/path/

I dont know, but this here dont work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^.*code=1.*$ /post/path/ [L]
```

if I run http://domain.com/post/path/?code=4/oWTYGaoOsyts
there will be nothing change.

```
[REQUEST_URI] => /post/path/?code=1/oWTYGaoOsyts
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[PHP_SELF] => /index.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For searching a parameter in the URL, you need to use RewriteCond and %{QUERY_STRING}:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*code=1.*$
RewriteRule .* /post/path/ [L]
```

From the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> Syntax:   RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
>
> In Directory and
> htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the
> filesystem path, after removing the prefix that led the server to the
> current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending
> on where the directives are defined).
>
> If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use
> a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or
> %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're searching for `code=1` and you pass `code=4`

This should work with given input

`RewriteRule ^.*code=4.*$ /post/path/ [L]`

Note that it can match unintended urls like `code=40` or `somecode=4`